# How to handle global variables in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, global-variables

I just want to have an array as global, so when I add or remove an element,
it can be reflected anywhere in the class.

For example:

```
class something
  @@my_array = Array.new
  def self.action_1
    @@my_array << 1
    @@my_array << 2
    @@my_array << 3
  end

   def self.how_many_elements
     puts "# of elements: " + @@my_array.size.to_s
   end
end
```

If i do the following:

> something.action_1 => **from controller_a**
>
> something.how_many_elements => **from controller b**

I always get the following output:

```
"# of elements: 0"
```

Why?

Comment: Quite aside from the fact that @@class variables won't do what you want here, it's never a good idea to use @@class variables in Ruby. Forget that they exist; use class @instance variables instead -- they function similarly but with fewer surprises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a common mistake to think that you can stash things in your classes and they will persist between requests. If this happens it is purely coincidence and it is a behavior you cannot depend on.

Using global variables in this fashion is almost a bad idea. A properly structured Rails application should persist data in the `session`, the database, or the `Rails.cache` subsystem.

Each request serviced by Rails in development mode will start with a virtually clean slate, where all models, controllers, views and routes are reloaded from scratch each time. If you put things in a class thinking it will be there for you the next time around, you're going to be in for a surprise.

For saving things that are not important, use the Rails cache or the session facility. For saving things that are important, use a database.

Answer (score 1):

Use class variables:

```
class something

  @@my_array = []

  def self.action_1
    @@my_array << 1
    @@my_array << 2
    @@my_array << 3
  end

   def self.how_many_elements
     puts "# of elements: " + @@my_array.size
   end
end
```

Comment: Either would work under normal circumstances, although class variables would be preferable. Turns out it's unrelated to the type, though.